# jQuery click events not always firing

Tags: jquery

We have several buttons and checkboxes that have jQuery click events defined for them in document.ready that perform ajax callbacks. On our test server they always work correctly in all major browsers (IE, FF, Safari, and Chrome). We log enough information on the server to determine that they're firing correctly.

However, on very rare occasions we've found in production that they're apparently not firing at all for a few random users, but we can't come close to reproducing this problem ourselves.

We know that Javascript is enabled for these users. We've seen the problem with both IE8 and Safari, but it hasn't occurred enough times to definitely correlate it to a specific browser/version.

We're currently using jQuery version 1.6.2.

Any ideas on what might be causing this problem?

Comment: One possibility is that the events are not being attached to the DOM because your Javascript is executed before the DOM is ready. Make sure that your handlers are `$(document).ready` wrapped.

Comment: Is it possible in the app that the user can fire more than one event on a page?  What I am thinking is that it's possible the first ajax call hasn't completed before they try to fire another ajax request which sometimes will work and sometimes not.  Are you using the .done, .defer .promise functions to make sure the events are done before more actions are taken? In test and production (local) you wouldn't have measurable lag.

Comment: The "clicks" are defined within document.ready. One of the clicks is attached to a submit button. The first thing it does is check the value of a hidden variable, but this doesn't seem to be firing. It makes a .ajax callback with async:false, which also doesn't seem to be firing. That is, it doesn't look like the 1st ajax call is firing at all, and not a case of the 1st one working but the 2nd one failing.